# how to mess up a sequence of numbers?

Tags: java

I need a sort of algorithm or a library that can do this stuf:

I suppose to have an integer sequence of numbers that starts with 0 and ends with n number, such as:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

I want to mess up this sequnce of numbers by a numeric key, so i use as key 378 and the algoritm give me this new sequence of numbers:

```
7,5,3,11,0,9,4,1,8,10,2
```

so my question is. There is a sort of algoritm or library that can do this in java?

Comment: what do you mean by this? you want to shuffle the list?

Comment: i want this exactly!

Comment: I don't think is an exact duplicate, as the OP wants to pass in a custom source of randomness.

Comment: @JacobG. You can seed the random number generator, for repeatable results. You can even supply your own implementation of `Random` if a specific randomization algorithm is desired.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's what I specified in my answer.  However, the duplicate question mentions nothing about that.  It seems the duplicate of the duplicate mentions it, but in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.shuffle` allows you to pass in your own source of randomness, so you can use 378 as the seed and always receive the same shuffled list:

```
var numbers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);

Collections.shuffle(numbers, new Random(378));

System.out.println(numbers);
```

Output:

```
[4, 10, 3, 2, 0, 7, 9, 11, 5, 6, 1, 8]
```